# Checking whether an org headline or any of its parents is done

Tags: org-mode

One can use `org-entry-is-done-p` to check whether a headline is *locally* done:

```
(defun org-entry-is-done-p ()
  (member (org-get-todo-state) org-done-keywords))
```

So for example `Task B` is considered "done" using this methodology:

```
* Task A
** COMPLETE Task B
   CLOSED: [2021-03-08 Mon 15:51]
*** Task C
```

**Question:** How can one modify this function that it will consider `Task C` also done?  That is, how can one make a function that checks whether the current headline or any of its parents is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(outline-up-heading 1)` to step up through the subtree headings, checking each one as you go. You are done when you've checked the top level of the subtree.

Here's an implementation:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
(defun ndk/org-entry-is-hierarchically-done-p ()
  (catch 'exit
    (save-excursion
      (while t
        ;; if this is a DONE entry, return t
        (when (org-entry-is-done-p)
          (throw 'exit t))
        ;; if we are at top level, return nil
        (when (= (org-outline-level) 1)
          (throw 'exit nil))
        ;; if we cannot go up any further, return nil
        (when (not (outline-up-heading 1))
          (throw 'exit nil))))))

  #+end_src
```

We loop over all the levels. At each level, starting from the lowest and going up, we check if the state is `DONE`: if so, we break out of the loop immediately returning `t`. If not, we check whether we are at the top level and if so, break out of the loop returning `nil`. Otherwise we check whether we can go up a level: if not, we return `nil`; if yes, we try again at the new level.

Comment: Is there a way to acommodate for the case when the root heading doesn't have `org-outline-level 1` (i.e. the root heading starts at a sublevel)?

Comment: See the revised code. I believe it fixes the bug.

Comment: The function gets stuck in the first `when` statement when the root level has an outline-level greater than 1.

Comment: I tested with the root level being at level 1 an also at level 2 and it worked in both cases. Can you post a sample document on which it does not work? You can edit your question and add it.

Comment: Apologies. My mistake.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!